# how to get full width in my wordpress page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I have to create a full-width page template in Wordpress. But I don't understand why, even if I only call my 'sidebar-bas' I also have the 'sidebar-droite' displayed :/

i hope someone could help me

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Full Width
*/
?>
<?php get_header();
if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
        <section id="pages" class="haut avecAside">
        <section id="pages" class="haut">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        </section>
    <?php endwhile;
    endif;
    get_sidebar( 'sidebar-bas' );
    get_footer();?>
```

Comment: The title of the question does not match the question itself. So, are you trying to get one side bar but it is displaying another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that your **sidebar-bas** template file does not include `get_sidebar( 'sidebar-droite' )` in it.

Comment: Yes you were right! it was including both, thanks a lot ;)